# Function pointers and overridden functions in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and I'm now  confused about the polymorphism concept and function pointers. It's kinda mixed up in my head. 
 
In the code snipped below, I declare a function pointer that points to a method in BaseClass. Then I assigned it with &BaseClass::Print 
 
 
The last two lines is the part i get confused: why these two lines doesn't yield the same result? I guess it's because the pointer myPtr points to the v-table, but i'm not sure. Also, if I want to make myPtr call the overridden BaseClass::Print() function, how could I do so? 

Could anyone please clarify this to me? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BaseClass{
    public:
        virtual void Print(){
            cout << "Hey!" << endl;
        }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        void Print(){
            cout << "Derived!" << endl;
        } 
};

int main()
{
    BaseClass *b = new DerivedClass;

    void (BaseClass::*myPtr)();

    myPtr = &BaseClass::Print;

    (b->*myPtr)(); //print "Derived!"
    b->BaseClass::Print(); //print "Hey!"
}
```

Comment: A good read if you want to know a bit more about the nitty gritty of member function pointers:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

Comment: Aside: Perhaps unintuitively, if print were to not be virtual, both would print "Hey!".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `(b->*myPtr)();` calls the `BaseClass::Print` member of `b`. `BaseClass::Print` is a virtual function and, since you're calling it through a pointer type, will be looked up polymorphically. That is, the correct function according to the dynamic type of `b` (which is `DerivedClass`) will be found.

The second line `b->BaseClass::Print();` explicitly calls the `Print` member function that is a member of `BaseClass`. That's precisely what this syntax is for. It says "Hey, I don't care what the dynamic type of `b` is - I want you to call the `BaseClass` version."

Comment: this indeed clarify things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even though you created object of type `DerivedClass` it still has information about class from which it inherits, in that case - `BaseClass`. So when you are using:

`b->BaseClass::Print();`

You just ask to call `Print()` method from it's parent - `BaseClass`.